# Schema and consistency of database - keys, triggers, or something else?

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database, database-schema

I am making a school project in sql server, and I am having a problem with my database schema.

**Problem**:
Database is made for a company which organises conferences. Each conference has its days and workshops. If a customer wants to enroll for a workshop, he needs to enroll for proper conference, than for proper day, and finally for this workshop.
I made a schema:

**Solution 1**
[image: Option1]

I found it great, but with this approach triggers are necessary - to make sure that customer enrolling eg for workshop is enrolled for a proper day. So I came on another idea:

**Solution 2**

[image: Option2]

This lets me to get rid of triggers, but I have so many keys, that any nontrivial query will be very sophisticated.

**Question**: So which approach is better? Or do You know another, more appropriate option?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is some additional logic I am not inferring, even the second model won't prevent the insertion of an entry in WorkshopEnrollments without a corresponding entry in DayEnrollments and/or an entry in ConferenceEnrollments.

Try:

```
[ConferenceEnrollments]  [DayEnrollments]             [WorkshopEnrollments]
id (PK)                  id (PK)                      id (PK)
customerid (FK)          conferenceenrollmentid (FK)  dayenrollmentid (FK)
conferenceid (FK)        dayid (FK)                   workshopid (FK)
```

The above model requires that before a DayEnrollments entry can be inserted, a ConferenceEnrollments entry exist. Likewise with WorkshopEnrollments and DayEnrollments.

Non-Trivial queries will still be onerous but it seems that consistency is more important for your project.

Comment: _"even the second model won't prevent the insertion of an entry in WorkshopEnrollments without a corresponding entry in DayEnrollments"_ could You give an example?

Comment: btw, Your model allows a customer enrolled for one conference to enroll for any day of any conference (same situation with days and workshops)...

Comment: Yes, you are correct that someone could enter a record into WorkshopEnrollments with a dayenrollmentid which references a different day than the workshop that is being scheduled.

While you may, ultimately, be able to enforce that depth of constraint using purely PK/FK combinations .. I believe the simpler answer would be to enforce some of the logic requirements in the application layer. Is that a possibility for this project?

Comment: I apologize - I did not read the diagram correctly. I see now that the relationship between DayEnrollments and WorkshopEnrollments is a compound key on customerid/conferenceid/dayid.  

Admittedly, your second model would afford you considerable flexibility in reporting insofar as being able to query for all workshop enrollments for a given conference through a query against a single table. Something the other two models would require the joining of at least two other tables.

If you are able to leverage views, you could simplify many of your ad-hoc queries this way.